# Wrong translation of filepaths to utf-8 by PyQt4 using Python 3.4

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, qt4, pyqt4

I recently moved my PyQt4 application from Python 2.7 to Python 3.4. But I've noticed that my QDirIterator returns wrongly decoded nonscii filepaths. I am using API v2, so QString is directly being translated to python str object. But translated filepaths are wrong.

i.e.

```
Right paths are (from python os module):

D:\Dropbox\MP3\Chinaski\2002 - Originál\01 - Můj svět.mp3 
D:\Dropbox\MP3\Chinaski\2002 - Originál\02 - Veselý turista.mp3 
D:\Dropbox\MP3\Chinaski\2002 - Originál\03 - Láskopad.mp3 
D:\Dropbox\MP3\Chinaski\2002 - Originál\04 - Hurá do Chebu.mp3 
D:\Dropbox\MP3\Chinaski\2002 - Originál\05 - Kytarista.mp3 
D:\Dropbox\MP3\Chinaski\2002 - Originál\06 - Žil byl....mp3 
D:\Dropbox\MP3\Chinaski\2002 - Originál\07 - Lidi choděj do práce.mp3 
D:\Dropbox\MP3\Chinaski\2002 - Originál\08 - Dobrák od Kosti.mp3 
D:\Dropbox\MP3\Chinaski\2002 - Originál\09 - Umělci z Prahy.mp3 
D:\Dropbox\MP3\Chinaski\2002 - Originál\10 - Šangri-la.mp3 
D:\Dropbox\MP3\Chinaski\2002 - Originál\11 - Dál....mp3 
D:\Dropbox\MP3\Chinaski\2002 - Originál\12 - Neříkej,že ne.mp3 
D:\Dropbox\MP3\Chinaski\2002 - Originál\13 - Tahle láska skončila.mp3

But QDirIterator returns (ignore slashes .. / or \ doesn't matter)

D:/Dropbox/MP3/Chinaski/2002 - Originál/01 - Moj svt.mp3 
D:/Dropbox/MP3/Chinaski/2002 - Originál/02 - Veselý turista.mp3 
D:/Dropbox/MP3/Chinaski/2002 - Originál/03 - Láskopad.mp3 
D:/Dropbox/MP3/Chinaski/2002 - Originál/04 - Hurá do Chebu.mp3 
D:/Dropbox/MP3/Chinaski/2002 - Originál/05 - Kytarista.mp3 
D:/Dropbox/MP3/Chinaski/2002 - Originál/06 - }il byl....mp3 
D:/Dropbox/MP3/Chinaski/2002 - Originál/07 - Lidi chodj do práce.mp3 
D:/Dropbox/MP3/Chinaski/2002 - Originál/08 - Dobrák od Kosti.mp3 
D:/Dropbox/MP3/Chinaski/2002 - Originál/09 - Umlci z Prahy.mp3 
D:/Dropbox/MP3/Chinaski/2002 - Originál/10 - `angri-la.mp3 
D:/Dropbox/MP3/Chinaski/2002 - Originál/11 - Dál....mp3 
D:/Dropbox/MP3/Chinaski/2002 - Originál/12 - NeYíkej,~e ne.mp3 
ila.mp3
```

Same QFile works returns nonsense:

```
ff = QFile("D:\\Dropbox\\MP3\\Chinaski\\2002 - Originál\\06 - Žil byl....mp3")
print(ff.fileName())
print(ff.fileName().encode())

> D:/Dropbox/MP3/Chinaski/2002 - Originál/06 - }il byl....mp3
> b'D:/Dropbox/MP3/Chinaski/2002 - Origin\xc3\xa1l/06 - }il byl....mp3'

# expected this byte path
print(b'D:/Dropbox/MP3/Chinaski/2002 - Origin\xc3\xa1l/06 - \xc5\xbdil byl....mp3'.decode())

> D:/Dropbox/MP3/Chinaski/2002 - Originál/06 - Žil byl....mp3
```

Now what? I've done some hocus-pocus with .encode and .decode, but i.e. char 'Ž' which is clearly more than 8-bit is translated to '}', so right information has been lost. Something bad is happening here.

- Windows 8.1 x64
- Python 3.4.2 x32
- PyQt4-4.11.2-gpl-Py3.4-Qt4.8.6-x32.exe

I've ported my code to Python 3 because of Python 2.7 unicode nightmare. Does anybody have a clue?

EDIT1:

This is original code snipet:

```
@pyqtSlot(str)
def scanFiles(self, targetDir):
    """
    Thread worker! Called asynchronously from main thread.
    The final data are sent to media parser in another thread.
    @type targetDir: str
    """
    # if target dir is already a file
    if targetDir.endswith(self.fileNamesFilter):
        logger.debug("Scanned target dir is a file.")
        self.parseDataSignal.emit([targetDir])
        self.parseDataSignal.emit([])             # end flag for media parser
        return

    flags = QDirIterator.Subdirectories | QDirIterator.FollowSymlinks if self.followSym else QDirIterator.Subdirectories
    dirIter = QDirIterator(targetDir, flags)
    result = []
    n = 0

    logger.debug("Dir iterator initialized, starting recursive search and parsing.")
    while dirIter.hasNext():
        path = dirIter.next()
        if path.endswith(self.fileNamesFilter):    # little bit slower than using regex (few ms), but more readable
            result.append(path)

            n += 1
            if n == self.SEND_LIMIT:
                self.parseDataSignal.emit(result)
                n = 0
                result = []

    if result:
        self.parseDataSignal.emit(result)

    logger.debug("Recursive search finished, sending finish_parser flag.")
    self.parseDataSignal.emit([])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found where the problem is. I have been using older version PyQt4-4.10.4, which obviously has this bug. Latest version PyQt4-4.11.2 works just fine just as PyQt5 versions. I've overlooked version number change, my bad.